# Datetime intervals with numpy.arange

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to create monthly intervals without iterating using np.arange.  As a simple example, I'd like an array containing a np.datetime64 object representing New Years Day for the range 1990-2000.  I'd think something like:

```
np.arange(np.datetime64("1990-01-01"), np.datetime64("2000-01-01"), np.timedelta64(1, 'M'), dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

but this raises the error

```
TypeError: Cannot cast NumPy timedelta64 scalar from metadata [M] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

If I switch dtype to datetime[M] I get an array of the months, but of course I want the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the original `dtype` to `datetime64[Y]` and then cast it to `datetime64[D]` with `.astype()`

```
np.arange(np.datetime64("1990-01-01"), np.datetime64("2000-01-01"), np.timedelta64(1, 'Y'), dtype='datetime64[Y]').astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: It can be shortened to: `np.arange("1990-01-01", "2000-01-01", 1, dtype='datetime64[Y]').astype('datetime64[D]')`.  The `dtype` will take care of converting the strings and integer to the 'Y' type.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch `np.timedelta64(1, 'M')` to `np.timedelta64(1, 'D')`

Comment: That will just give a range of each day between those dates (['1990-01-01', '1990-01-02', '1990-01-03'...].  I'm looking for the result ['1990-01-01', '1990-02-01', '1990-03-01'...]

Comment: `np.arange(...np.timedelta64(1, 'M'), dtype='datetime64[M]').astype('datetime64[D]')` would do?